# Serverless create command not working

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, npm, serverless-framework

I have installed node.js and the serverless framework. If I type:

```
serverless --version
```

Its showing the output as 1.26.1. However if I run the command below:

```
serverless --create --template aws-python3 --name numpy
```

Its throwing the o/p

```
Commands
* You can run commands with "serverless" or the shortcut "sls"
* Pass "--verbose" to this command to get in-depth plugin info
* Pass "--no-color" to disable CLI colors
* Pass "--help" after any <command> for contextual help

Framework
* Documentation: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/
```

What am I missing?

Comment: --create shouldn't be there

Answer (score 0):

create should be without hyphens --

```
serverless create --template aws-python3 --name numpy
```